# Required documents for minor U.S. citizen entering and returning from Canada

Tags: passports, us-citizens, borders, minors

My 17-year-old daughter's passport expired on April 1, 2015. She is a U.S. citizen. I need to know if she will be allowed to across the border from Rochester, New York to Canada and back from Canada to Detroit. She has with her the expired passport and her original birth certificate, and will be traveling with her mother.

Answer (score 2):

- Entering Canada by land: A birth certificate and photo identification should be [enough to enter Canada](http://cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ivc-rnc-eng.html#a1a).
- Returning to the U.S. by land: A birth certificate is [enough for children under 16](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative). But your daughter is 17. Children 16-18 can also cross with just a birth certificate if they are in some kind of a group; that probably doesn't help.

  An "enhanced driver's license" is also acceptable; only a few states have them, but New York and Michigan are included, if she is resident of either.

  Finally, as a U.S. citizen, she cannot be denied entry to the U.S. as long as she can satisfactorily prove that she is a U.S. citizen, though they may give her a hard time. To that end, an expired passport (especially one recently expired) will work well. A U.S. birth certificate with photo ID will also work.

Comment: Is this statement still valid for July 2017: "Returning to the U.S. by land: A birth certificate is enough for children under 16"? I couldn't find the info on the link

Comment: @Hoppe: I have updated the link